# Error testing spring boot 1.4 application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-test

I have very simple spring boot 1.4 application with one rest controller. When i tried to test the context loading of this i am getting error like below :-

```
13:29:03.623 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.c.j.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner - SpringJUnit4ClassRunner constructor called with [class com.byteobject.cloudsanthe.frontendservice.FrontendServiceApplicationTests]
13:29:03.628 [main] DEBUG o.s.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate from class [org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate]
13:29:03.632 [main] DEBUG o.s.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating BootstrapContext using constructor [public org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultBootstrapContext(java.lang.Class,org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate)]
13:29:03.641 [main] DEBUG o.s.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating TestContextBootstrapper for test class [com.byteobject.cloudsanthe.frontendservice.FrontendServiceApplicationTests] from class [org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper]
13:29:03.644 [main] INFO  o.s.b.t.c.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Neither @ContextConfiguration nor @ContextHierarchy found for test class [com.byteobject.cloudsanthe.frontendservice.FrontendServiceApplicationTests]
13:29:03.650 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.t.c.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - @TestExecutionListeners is not present for class [com.byteobject.cloudsanthe.frontendservice.FrontendServiceApplicationTests]: using defaults.
13:29:03.659 [main] INFO  o.s.b.t.c.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Loaded default TestExecutionListener class names from location [META-INF/spring.factories]: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.AutoConfigureReportTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener]
13:29:03.667 [main] INFO  o.s.b.t.c.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Could not instantiate TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener]. Specify custom listener classes or make the default listener classes (and their required dependencies) available. Offending class: [org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionAttribute]
13:29:03.671 [main] INFO  o.s.b.t.c.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Could not instantiate TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener]. Specify custom listener classes or make the default listener classes (and their required dependencies) available. Offending class: [org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionAttributeSource]
13:29:03.672 [main] INFO  o.s.b.t.c.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@2db7a79b, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener@6950e31, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.AutoConfigureReportTestExecutionListener@b7dd107, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@42eca56e, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@52f759d7, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener@7cbd213e, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener@192d3247, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener@3ecd23d9, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener@569cfc36]
13:29:03.674 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved @ProfileValueSourceConfiguration [null] for test class [com.byteobject.cloudsanthe.frontendservice.FrontendServiceApplicationTests]
13:29:03.674 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved ProfileValueSource type [class org.springframework.test.annotation.SystemProfileValueSource] for class [com.byteobject.cloudsanthe.frontendservice.FrontendServiceApplicationTests]
13:29:03.690 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved @ProfileValueSourceConfiguration [null] for test class [com.byteobject.cloudsanthe.frontendservice.FrontendServiceApplicationTests]
13:29:03.690 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved ProfileValueSource type [class org.springframework.test.annotation.SystemProfileValueSource] for class [com.byteobject.cloudsanthe.frontendservice.FrontendServiceApplicationTests]
13:29:03.691 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved @ProfileValueSourceConfiguration [null] for test class [com.byteobject.cloudsanthe.frontendservice.FrontendServiceApplicationTests]
13:29:03.691 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved ProfileValueSource type [class org.springframework.test.annotation.SystemProfileValueSource] for class [com.byteobject.cloudsanthe.frontendservice.FrontendServiceApplicationTests]
13:29:03.692 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved @ProfileValueSourceConfiguration [null] for test class [com.byteobject.cloudsanthe.frontendservice.FrontendServiceApplicationTests]
13:29:03.692 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved ProfileValueSource type [class org.springframework.test.annotation.SystemProfileValueSource] for class [com.byteobject.cloudsanthe.frontendservice.FrontendServiceApplicationTests]
13:29:03.695 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.c.s.AbstractDirtiesContextTestExecutionListener - Before test class: context [DefaultTestContext@67b467e9 testClass = FrontendServiceApplicationTests, testInstance = [null], testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@47db50c5 testClass = FrontendServiceApplicationTests, locations = '{}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextLoader = 'null', parent = [null]]], class annotated with @DirtiesContext [false] with mode [null].
13:29:03.696 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved @ProfileValueSourceConfiguration [null] for test class [com.byteobject.cloudsanthe.frontendservice.FrontendServiceApplicationTests]
13:29:03.696 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved ProfileValueSource type [class org.springframework.test.annotation.SystemProfileValueSource] for class [com.byteobject.cloudsanthe.frontendservice.FrontendServiceApplicationTests]
13:29:03.697 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.c.s.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener - Performing dependency injection for test context [[DefaultTestContext@67b467e9 testClass = FrontendServiceApplicationTests, testInstance = com.byteobject.cloudsanthe.frontendservice.FrontendServiceApplicationTests@548ad73b, testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@47db50c5 testClass = FrontendServiceApplicationTests, locations = '{}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextLoader = 'null', parent = [null]]]].
13:29:03.699 [main] ERROR o.s.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.AutoConfigureReportTestExecutionListener@b7dd107] to prepare test instance [com.byteobject.cloudsanthe.frontendservice.FrontendServiceApplicationTests@548ad73b]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.AutoConfigureReportTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(AutoConfigureReportTestExecutionListener.java:49)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:249)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot load an ApplicationContext with a NULL 'contextLoader'. Consider annotating your test class with @ContextConfiguration or @ContextHierarchy.
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:115)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 24 common frames omitted
13:29:03.705 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.c.s.AbstractDirtiesContextTestExecutionListener - After test class: context [DefaultTestContext@67b467e9 testClass = FrontendServiceApplicationTests, testInstance = [null], testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@47db50c5 testClass = FrontendServiceApplicationTests, locations = '{}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextLoader = 'null', parent = [null]]], class annotated with @DirtiesContext [false] with mode [null].
```

test class is :-

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment=WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class FrontendServiceApplicationTests {

@Test
public void contextLoads() {
}

}
```

And application class is :-

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource({"classpath:dbContext.xml",        "classpath:dbClientMappingContext.xml"})
public class FrontendServiceApplication {

/**
 * The main method.
 *
 * @param args the arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(FrontendServiceApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

What i am doing wrong here?

Comment: `Consider annotating your test class with @ContextConfiguration or @ContextHierarchy.
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:115)`

Comment: Ensure that test class and impl class is in the same package. This was the issue for me when having `@WebMvcTest` on test class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like Spring Boot cannot find your `@SpringBootApplication` class using classpath scanning.

So give the following a try:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(
    classes = FrontendServiceApplication.class,
    webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT
)
public class FrontendServiceApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Sam, yes the issue was related to classpath, gradle had messedup my settings.