# java spring unit test failure , failed to load ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, junit

I'm trying to do a unit test in my application to test a a method on service layer.

I have the following classes.

**AbstractTest.java**

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import com.equadis.webapp.controller.UserController;

//inform spring which class to use when executing unit test
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)

@SpringBootTest(classes=UserController.class)
public abstract class AbstractTest {
    protected Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());


}
```

and

**UserServiceTest.java that extends AbstractTest**

```
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.equadis.webapp.DAO.UserDAO;
import com.equadis.webapp.entity.UserVO;
import com.equadis.webapp.test.AbstractTest;



@Transactional
public class UserServiceTest extends AbstractTest {

    @Autowired
    private UserService service;


    @Before
    public void setup(){
        service = new UserService();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown(){
        //clean up after each test method
    }


    @Test
    public void getListByID() {
        UserVO user = service.getListByID(1);
        System.out.println(user);
        Assert.assertNotNull("failure - expected not null", user);
        Assert.assertEquals("failure - expected id", 1, user.getId());
    }

}
```

Noting that in Abstract.java class

```
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
```

was replaced by

```
@SpringBootTest(classes=UserController.class)
```

So when i run a unit test i get the following errors:

**Stack trace:**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:201)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:255)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:111)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:148)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:51)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner$1.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:37)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:42)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not build an ApplicationContext with a NULL 'contextLoader'. Consider annotating your test class with @ContextConfiguration.
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:115)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:169)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:197)
    ... 17 more
```

Any help concerning this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error testing spring boot 1.4 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39485760/error-testing-spring-boot-1-4-application)

Comment: This link also :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39485760/error-testing-spring-boot-1-4-application

Comment: Please include you context configuration file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks everyone for your help , after reading all your comments and doing some research i've figured out the solution , with adding the following annotation:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"/myxmlfile.xml"})
```

that contain the confiuration.

Answer (score 3):

The `classes` field in the `@SpringBootTest` is the place you tell your application where your main Application Configuration is. It is not the place you specify your test classes. It should be like this,

```
@SpringBootTest(classes=Application.class)
```

Besides, I think you are using old version of Spring boot. I think in 1.4/ 1.5 they moved Test class to,

```
@Runwith(SpringRunner.class)
```

Comment: thank you for your reply , i actually don't have a main Application Configuration class , i'm using xml files that contain the configuration , any idea how to refer to them? @techtabu

Comment: If you have a Spring boot application, you should have an Application.class, don't you?